# DAX - Grand Total not adding up to Row Total

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a powerbi report which is running a dax formula to calculate a custom measure. In the picture below, the total at the bottom doesn't seem to add up to the individual rows. I've been trying my luck for some time and can't seem to figure out why this is.

[image]

The DAX formula used is as follows

```
SumRest<24hrs7Day = CALCULATE(
                DISTINCTCOUNT(WorkTimeDirective[EmployeeKey]),
                FILTER(
                    ADDCOLUMNS(
                        SUMMARIZE(WorkTimeDirective,Employee[EmployeeKey],'Date'[DateKey]),
                            "totRestHrs", CALCULATE(MAX(WorkTimeDirective[RestHours])
                                ,DATESINPERIOD('Date'[DateKey], LASTDATE('Date'[DateKey]), -7, DAY))
                        ),
                    [totRestHrs]<24
                ),
                WorkTimeDirective[IsEmployeeAbove18]=1
            )
```

Any idea why this is and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just a guess here, but you are doing a distinct count of the employee. If an employee were able to have two events on two different sites then you would get exactly that.

Comment: Makes sense. Appears I need to use the SUMX function instead to iterate over the individual rows? I tried that, but can't get it to work. Any idea how to best adjust it. Sorry my DAX knowledge is very poor.

Answer (score 1):

For using `SUMX` the main step is listing the values which you are iterating over, which it typically a table or column.  In this case it sounds like you would do a column.

For the example I just had it call the measure you already defined, since breaking DAX calculations into smaller pieces makes writing/testing complex formulas easier.

The idea being that it would iterate over the unique values which are in your TableName[Site Name], then run the [SumRest<24hrs7Day] under that context.  I used TableName for the table due to not knowing the name for the table.

```
SUMX_Example = SUMX( VALUES( TableName[Site Name], [SumRest<24hrs7Day])
```